# Extract multiple matches using a pattern from a String

Tags: r, stringr

I want to extract some substrings from a bigger string using some pattern. Below is my code:

```
library(stringr)
str_extract_all("'abcd:3343', sdgshdg374 'rgjrkgj4252:sfsfd', wdwdw'wdwd:364:ssfd', 3434", "[''][a-zA-Z0-9]['']")
```

Basically, I want to match pattern like `['][anything with any length][']` and followed by `,[space`]. Therefore I was expecting I should get matches as `'abcd:3343'` & `'rgjrkgj4252:sfsfd'` & `'wdwd:364:ssfd'`. Notice that for each above cases, all substrings are followed by `,[space]`

With my above code, I am getting no match.

Can you please help how to construct right pattern match for this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may need to add `:` also

```
library(stringr)
str_extract_all("'abcd:3343', sdgshdg374 'rgjrkgj4252:sfsfd', 
       wdwdw'wdwd:364:ssfd', 3434", "'[A-Za-z0-9:# ]+'")[[1]]
```

-output

```
[1] "'abcd:3343'"         "'rgjrkgj4252:sfsfd'" "'wdwd:364:ssfd'"
```

---

Or it could be also to match the `'` followed by one or more characters that are not `'` (`[^']+`) and the `'`

```
str_extract_all("'abcd:3343', sdgshdg374 'rgjrkgj4252:sfsfd', 
       wdwdw'wdwd:364:ssfd', 3434", "'[^']+'")[[1]]
[1] "'abcd:3343'"         "'rgjrkgj4252:sfsfd'" "'wdwd:364:ssfd'"
```

Comment: Many thanks. But it is not matching some of the cases e.g. `'rgjrkgj4252:sf#sfd'` or `'wdwd:364:ss fd'` i.e. if I have `#` '[space]' etc. How can I modify above syntax?

Comment: @DanielLobo change the code to `"'[A-Za-z0-9:# ]+'"`

Comment: Please note that the regex is based on the pattern example and the desired outptut you showed.  If there are other cases, you may need to show that